# AngularJS Filteriing Search Result: Error: [ng:areq]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter a search result in angularjs and am getting this error on my chrome console: Error: [ng:areq]

This is my code snippet

```
<div id="notebooks" ng-controller="NotebookListCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query"/>
  <select ng-model="orderList">
    <option value="name">By name</option>
    <option value="-age">Newest</option>
    <option value="age">Oldest</option>
  </select>
  <ul id="notebook_ul">
    <li ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | filter:query | orderBy: orderList">
      name: {{notebook.name}}<br/>
      procesor: {{notebook.procesor}}<br/>
      <div class="right top">{{notebook.age}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>Number of notebooks: {{notebooks.length}}</span>
</div>
```

This is the plunk I have made
http://plnkr.co/edit/P1DFr3fEuWiYGfC0k7bj?p=preview

Everything seems okay but I don't know why I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define controller properly as below

updated : http://plnkr.co/edit/P1DFr3fEuWiYGfC0k7bj?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller('NotebookListCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.notebooks = [
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "procesor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2011},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2010},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
     "age": 2008},
    {"name": "HP",
     "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
     "age": 2012},
    {"name": "Acer",
     "procesor": "AMD",
     "age": 2006},
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "procesor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2009},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2008},
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "procesor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2011},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2010},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
     "age": 2008},
    {"name": "HP",
     "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
     "age": 2012},
    {"name": "Acer",
     "procesor": "AMD",
     "age": 2006},
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "procesor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2009},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2008},
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "procesor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2011},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2010},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
     "age": 2008},
    {"name": "HP",
     "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
     "age": 2012},
    {"name": "Acer",
     "procesor": "AMD",
     "age": 2006},
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "procesor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2009},
    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "procesor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2008}
  ];

  $scope.orderList = "name";

}]);
```

Comment: @JnG , . yes you can , though your repeating . certainly use 'ng-src' directive  which provides the path for the image for  the img tags in your view .

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module("myApp",["ngSanitize"])
.controller('NotebookListCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.notebooks = [
      {"name": "Lenovo",
       "procesor": "Intel i5",
       "age": 2011},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel i7",
       "age": 2010},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
       "age": 2008},
      {"name": "HP",
       "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
       "age": 2012},
      {"name": "Acer",
       "procesor": "AMD",
       "age": 2006},
      {"name": "Lenovo",
       "procesor": "Intel i5",
       "age": 2009},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel i7",
       "age": 2008},
      {"name": "Lenovo",
       "procesor": "Intel i5",
       "age": 2011},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel i7",
       "age": 2010},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
       "age": 2008},
      {"name": "HP",
       "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
       "age": 2012},
      {"name": "Acer",
       "procesor": "AMD",
       "age": 2006},
      {"name": "Lenovo",
       "procesor": "Intel i5",
       "age": 2009},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel i7",
       "age": 2008},
      {"name": "Lenovo",
       "procesor": "Intel i5",
       "age": 2011},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel i7",
       "age": 2010},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
       "age": 2008},
      {"name": "HP",
       "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
       "age": 2012},
      {"name": "Acer",
       "procesor": "AMD",
       "age": 2006},
      {"name": "Lenovo",
       "procesor": "Intel i5",
       "age": 2009},
      {"name": "Toshiba",
       "procesor": "Intel i7",
       "age": 2008}
    ];
    $scope.orderList = "name";
  }
]);
```

Comment: Your answer is approach is okay.

Answer (score 0):

The error is

```
Argument 'NotebookListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Which is findable if you click [the url](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=NotebookListCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined) next to [ng:areq] in the browser console

you're getting this error because you have not defined a controller in the correct way.  AngularJS after 1.2 doesn't allow for the "controller as global function" syntax, instead you need to add it to your module, like so:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('NotebookListCtrl',NotebookListCtrl);
```

to do minification-safe injection, you should also do the following

```
NotebookListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Comment: I have gotten solution to my attempt! Thanks